# Error installing Fastlane on project

Tags: ios, build, itunes, fastlane

Trying to install fastlane on my project.

Terminal:

When I am in the directory where my project is present and trying to install fastlane, it goes wrong, when I typed my Apple ID it starts to log me in, it throws:

> Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect
>
> An error accured during the setup process.

The app is already on App Store, but I want to use fastlane on this app so i can use  it on the project there is on the mac when I need to update it later.

What can I do to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not fastlane specific - its sorta ssl ruby problem.
hits a lot of tools see:

- https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6553#issuecomment-254199307
- https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/253

if you are using rvm maybe the following works for you:

```
brew upgrade openssl
brew link --force openssl
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.5 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
```

replace `2.1.5` with your ruby version.